# rtl8723be Realtek Wifi-Card driver not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers, kernel-modules, realtek

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my new Lenovo G50-70. The wifi works perfectly in windows, however it behaves strangely on Ubuntu. It is slow, doesn't load heavier sites at all, and after a while, completely drops.

After some research I discovered: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1320070

`sudo rmmod rtl8723be && sudo modprobe rtl8723be` does not change anything, the wifi remains gone.

The first thing I tried was `sudo make install` the driver from this repo: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new. Unfortunately nothing changed.

Next I tried to disable the sleep feature:
`echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`, without any luck.

I then tried:
`sudo rmmod -v ideapad_laptop`
But removing that module did not help either.

Here is some environment info:

```
uname -a
Linux zirconcode 3.13.0-40-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 13 17:53:56 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsusb | grep Rea
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller

lsmod | grep rtl
rtl8723be             139336  0 
btcoexist             183378  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                39740  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi               121008  3 btcoexist,rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              626557  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

I am stuck as none of the solutions seem to work. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Switching form the 3.13 to the 3.16 kernel and reinstalling the new drivers seems to have done the trick. Will post as answer if it holds.

Comment: I am sadly having the same problem, tried everything but the connection still drops, well the rate has decreased significantly by updating the driver [driver](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) but its still present, i also disabled the sleep feature by `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` your second post seems to be written 2 hours later from your first post, is it working flawlessly or have you bumped into problems again ? The drivers for this wlan card seems to be horrid. It would be very much appreciated if you can confirm.

Comment: @Akash Everything's been running flawlessly since then. The drivers are indeed horrible, Realtek isn't being supportive at all. Is your kernel 3.16 or newer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading my kernel from 3.13 to 3.16 (http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/) and reinstalling the new driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new seems to have solved my problems. Don't forget to reboot.

Note: Upgrading the kernel in itself did not help.