# Realtek 8723be wireless support, PC-BSD

Tags: realtek, pc-bsd

I have an HP 455 Probook with AMD10-7300 processor and Realtek 8723be wireless card. I would like to install PC-BSD. Is there any hope of wireless working?
I wish there was a live disk I could use to test before installing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a real hard time with my wireless card on a HP Probook 450 G2 with a rtl8723be chipset. I had to install the drivers from here: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

From all of the research I did when I had issues I found that I had to:

- update kernel to at least 3.16
- clone the git repo
- remove the loaded kernel module
- compile the module from the git repo
- disable power management in the module config
- load the module

Since I did those things all of my own wifi issues have gone.

I'm not using PC-BSD. I am using Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon Edition.

You can find most of the info I found in this stackexchange answer:
[rtl8723be Realtek Wifi-Card driver not working on Ubuntu 14.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170012/rtl8723be-realtek-wifi-card-driver-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04)

edit: for Linux Mint users I have summarised the steps here: http://www.thesysadmiral.co.uk/2015/11/linux-mint-on-hp-probook-450-g2-or.html